# Core Graphics: How to draw overlapped semi transparent rectangle without changing color of the common area

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

When two semi-transparent overlaps, the part in the middle will combines and blends into a darker color. Is there any way to draw rect as usual, but keep the overlapped part same color and transparency as remaining part of the rect?

Comment: Please, mark answers as accepted if you have your answer. It encourages community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate the intersection with

```
rect = CGRectIntersection(bottomRect, topRect)
```

Then draw the `bottomRect`, then fill the calculated `rect` with the default solid background color and draw the `topRect` on top of it.

Comment: If I get the intersection rect, how am I supposed to subtract that rect from either of the overlapping ones? Otherwise it looks like the same problem.

Comment: You don't need to subtract. Draw over the bottom rect with the solid background color of the `UIView`.

Comment: Thanks, that should solve the problem when background is solid color or repeatable patterns.